# type 'Future<Null>' is not a subtype of type 'String' in type cast in flutter and Firebase

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to query list by mentioned location in user document.

*1. All_Data is a main Collection in Firebase.
2. User_In is a SubCollection inside a document in a main collection in Firebase.
3. Area is a Field in a Document which stores user Area in String form.*

```
final user_loc =  FirebaseFirestore.instance
    .collection('All_Data')
    .doc(user.uid)
    .collection('User_In')
    .doc(user.uid)
    .get()
    .then((value) async {
  print(await value.get('Area'));
}) as String;
```

```
final Stream<QuerySnapshot> datastream = FirebaseFirestore.instance
    .collection('All_Data')
    .where("private", isEqualTo: false)
    .where("Area", isEqualTo: user_loc)
    .snapshots();
```

**Here is What I want...**
Every User has their own specific area mentioned in subcollection('User_In').doc(user.uid), I want Streambuilder to show only those documents from the main collection that contains Area is equal to the Area in subcollection('User_In').doc(user.uid).

**Here is What I tried...**
I have Mentioned the code above, I am trying to insert values to query them in the final stream datastream

**Here is What I get...**
Error I am Getting is "type 'Future' is not a subtype of type 'String' in type cast".

I am new to it please help me with what needs to be done, Or is it just fundamentally not possible with Firebase.

Answer (score 0):

You can get it like

```dart
() async {
  final value = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection('All_Data')
      .doc(user.uid)
      .collection('User_In')
      .doc(user.uid)
      .get();

  final user_loc = value.get('Area') as String?;
}
```

Edit:

```dart
class _FaState extends State<Fa> {
  Future<String?> fetchUserloc() async {
    final value = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('All_Data')
        .doc(user.uid)
        .collection('User_In')
        .doc(user.uid)
        .get();
    final user_loc = value.get('Area') as String?;
    return user_loc;
  }

  Future<Stream<QuerySnapshot>> getMyStream() async {
    final user_loc = await fetchUserloc();
    return FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('All_Data')
        .where("private", isEqualTo: false)
        .where("Area", isEqualTo: user_loc)
        .snapshots();
  }

  late final userStreamFuture = getMyStream();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: [
          FutureBuilder<Stream<QuerySnapshot>>(
            future: userStreamFuture,
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.hasData) {
                // you will get the steam here
              }

              return CircularProgressIndicator();
            },
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: i did exactly what you mentioned, I have errors on ( ), async, await and it says user_loc is unused.

Comment: It is an warning that you didnt used it, you can return it if you want . simply `return user_loc;}`

Comment: I Added ***' main '*** before **( )** and returned user_loc; as you said just after ** String?; ** , It removed the error from ( ), async and await. But now in *** .where("Area", isEqualTo: user_loc) *** user_loc says user_loc is undefined.

Comment: For your information, I am using StreamBuilder to fetch the document as a list.

Comment: I depend on your code structure, you can pass the variable or just call the method to fetch it and use the value, or create a state variable for this

Comment: Could you help me Write the code to Call the method to fetch it and then use the value...?

Comment: Its a really long time I am stuck on it...It would be a Big help...

Comment: nope that wont be `main`, it will your define method , let me do an update

Comment: There is one thing, the `user_loc` comes from future, seems like we need nested Future and stream builder, cant remember better way

Comment: Dear Yeasin, Thanks So far ...What to do with " itemCount: snapshot.data!.docs.length" and " DocumentSnapshot pull = snapshot.data!.docs[index]; "  it was in the Streambuilder but now in the future builder there's an error on ""docs"" . Rest looks fine...